# How can i return multiple lists from a function, retaining their names?

Tags: python, list, return

I have a function that creates multiple lists and I want to return them to the main body of the code with the same names that are used within the function.

The following example returns a concatenated list and then re-creates the individual lists (with the same names as used in the function), by slicing the concatenated list.

```py
def my_function():

    # Some code which generates multiple lists

    my_list_1 = [1, 2, 3]

    my_list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    return [my_list_1, my_list_2]

    temp = my_function()

    my_list_1 = temp[0]

    my_list_2 = temp[1]

    print (my_list_1)

    print (my_list_2)
```

This approach seems 'clunky' (the full function creates about 30 lists), but iIhave not found a more efficient approach. Is there one?

Teaching myself python and this is my first post so please go easy :). Thanks

Comment: Why do you need them as `my_list1 = temp[0]; my_list2 = temp[1]` ? What are you going to do with `my_list1`, `my_list2` after that ? What's the big picture here ?

Comment: If a function returns a list of 30 list then do you need to store those 30 sublists into another 30 list variables?

Comment: `return my_list1, my _list2` and call it as `my_list_1, my_list_2 = my_function()`

Comment: han solo - data in the lists will be subject to various other functions etc.  I wanted to retain their original names, as they are highly descriptive of whats in them, to help me track their use in the rest of the code.

Comment: Objects don't have names. Variables have names, but you can't pass variables around. The lists are objects; they never had names, and you can't have Python automatically bring the names with the lists.

Comment: for further info guys, the function interrogates multiple text files and extracts different sets of data into various lists.  When the list is created the 'name' of it describes what data is in it.

Comment: @IainMcleod I'd just name my container well, rather than naming each subitems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function returns a lot of results, you should consider using a `namedtuple`

```py
from collections import namedtuple

def my_function():
    Results = namedtuple('Results', ['my_list_1', 'my_list_2'])
    my_list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
    my_list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    return Results(my_list_1, my_list_2)
```

You can then access the results by their field names

```py
>>> results = my_function()
>>> results.my_list_1
[1, 2, 3]

>>> results.my_list_2
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Check out [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) on named tuples

Comment: thanks, the "my_list_1, my_list_2 = my_function()" approach works well but still requires 'repeating' all the field names again outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most pythonic way:

```
my_list_1, my_list_2 = my_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into *args and **kwargs
if you have your function return [list1, list2]
You can refactor your code so that

list1, list2 = *my_function() and so on

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have to return a list `return [my_list_1, my_list_2]` but simply `return my_list_1, my_list_2`. This will return a **tuple** of lists, it is a better way to return multiple things (more suitable).

Why don't you use the `temp` variable directly to access of lists, rather than create `my_list_1`, `my_list_2` variables ? That being said, you could call your function as `my_list_1, my_list_2 = your_function()` if you need this.

Another way is to return a dict : `return { 'my_list_1': my_list_1, 'my_list_2': my_list_2 }` then, you are able to do the following snippet (but it is useful when the keys are very heterogeneous and not an enumeration as *my_list_N*, index would be sufficient in this case).

```
returned_lists = your_function()
print(returned_lists['my_list_1'])
print(returned_lists['my_list_2'])
```